# MIPS: Storing integer input into memory using sw causes address out of range error

Tags: arrays, assembly, stack, mips

I am trying to store a dynamic array into a program using a stack, by first reading an input n and then creating a stack with [n] inputs. However, when I try to store word, it creates an error that I don't understand.

```
.data                           
ask_for_size: .asciiz "\nInsert the array size\n"
ask_for_int: .asciiz "\nInput number\n"
input:  .space 16


.text 

Main:
  li    $v0,4
  la    $a0,ask_for_size
  syscall
  li    $v0,5
  la    $a0,input
  syscall
  add   $t0,$v0,$zero
  li    $sp,0x00001000  #stack pointer
  li    $s0,0x00001000  #base pointer
  la    $a0,ask_for_int

Loop1:
  li    $v0,4
  syscall
  li    $v0,5
  syscall
  sw    $v0,0($sp)

  addi  $sp,$sp,-4
  addi  $t0,$t0,-1
  bne   $t0,$zero,Loop1
  j Loop2

Loop2:
```

Comment: It seems like you are missing `Loop2`.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger and make sure that all the register values are correct, and that the addresses you're using refer to memory that your program has access to.

Comment: @BlueIce, sorry right now Loop2 is empty. It's at the bottom there.

Comment: I'm running my code in a MARS IDE. It simulates all of the registers and registers and this was the base address given to me by my class. all values of registers start at 0x0000 0000

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you add -4 to $sp before you sw $v0 into it?

```
addi  $sp,$sp,-4
sw    $v0,0($sp)
```

It seems to me that at this time you're overwriting past the end of $sp allocated for your process.

---

Also you load $a0 only once. Are you sure it does not get modified? Otherwise, maybe that would work better?

```
Loop1:
  li    $v0,4
  la    $a0,ask_for_int
  syscall
  ...
```

Comment: I get the same error when I switch the order of the two statements

Comment: I see that you set your stack with `li $sp,0x00001000 #stack pointer` Maybe that memory location, if it exists, is not writable?